# CSRF verification failed. Request aborted in Django rest framework sending the request from flutter

Tags: python, django, flutter, django-rest-framework, flutter-http

I've followed everything mentioned in both documentation of [Django rest-framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and [Flutter http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) but still getting the error ..here is my code :

**Django**

**Settings**

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

**View**

```py
@csrf_exempt
@permission_classes(["isAuthenticated"])
@api_view(['POST'])
def chanage_image(request):
    data = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
        token = request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'][6:]
        lang = request.META['HTTP_LANG']
        image = request.data['image']
        main_user = Token.objects.get(key=token).user
        app_user = AppUser.objects.get(main_user=main_user)
        format, imgstr = image.split(';base64,')
        ext = format.split('/')[-1]
        data = ContentFile(base64.b64decode(imgstr), name='temp.' + ext) # You can save this as file instance.
        app_user.image = data
        app_user.save()
        data = {"success": True, "details": AppUserSerializer(
            app_user).data, "message": "Image changed" if lang == "en" else "تم تغيير الصورة"}
        return Response(data, headers=get_headers())
```

**URLS**

```py
    path('chanage_image/', chanage_image,name="chanage_image"),
```

**Flutter**

**Request**

```dart
    Map<String, dynamic> body = {
      "image": base64Image,
    };


  Future<UserModel> changePlayerImage(Map<String, dynamic> body) async {
    return await httpClient.post('api/user/change-image',
        body: body,
        headers: {'referer': 'https://www.l-dawri.com/'}).then((response) {
      print(response.body);
      return UserModel.fromJson(response.body);
    });
  }
```

but still in the end am always getting this error :

```
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
You are seeing this message because this site requires a CSRF cookie when submitting forms.
```

Comment: given that you expect a token here `token = request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'][6:]` you are not sending it in your post

Comment: You need to add the authorization in the request headers like : Authorization : Token "your token value"

Answer (score 0):

First you don't sent authorization token into header request while use from drf TokenAuthentication

Also into drf is better  you use from class view api(like inheritance from APIView) replace def view's